# Rendering error in android studio 2.1.2

Tags: android

[image]
I am facing rendering problems errors again and again.I have also changed the previews API's but this error is not going.help please

Comment: change your api level 24 to  23

Comment: Kamran, have you checked the answer? Did it solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that **you are selecting a preview mode that can not handle the rendering**.

Click on the Android Icon on the upper right corner of the screen and select a lower version. Most of the rendering issues are caused due to 'Automatically Pick Best' decisions.

[image]

Regards,

Comment: @kamran consider marking it as correct so others may find this thread useful. Regards